# Direct2D: leave a region of a window render target untouched

Tags: direct2d

I am drawing to a regular `HwndRengerTarget` but other windows, which have nothing to do with Direct2D, overlap it.

The problem is that these windows get painted over when I draw to the `HwndRengerTarget`.

I would like to tell Direct2D not to touch a specific region of the `HwndRengerTarget` (i.e. don't touch the pixels that are already on the screen), so that these windows remain correctly visible.

Is that possible?

If I draw normally then call `RedrawWindow` on the windows, it flickers a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not arrange the windows (HWNDs) so that the Direct2D one is at the bottom of the z-index? It should be the first child of its parent. Then clipping will be automatic. You may need the WS_CLIPSIBLINGS window style.

Comment: Thanks but I tried SetWindowPos(childWindow, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE) and the sibling windows are still being painted over. The parent window is a dialog and I would like Direct2D to not overwrite the buttons and other controls of the parent when I draw on childWindow (with childWindowRenderTarget->BeginDraw() and EndDraw()). Maybe Direct2D, being "direct" and more hardware-oriented, just blits the direct2d pixel information to the window by treating it as a rectangle, and bypasses the win32 information on parents/children and z-orders, is that possible?

Comment: Hmm, well I've had this working before (proof: http://blog.getpaint.net/2010/04/03/direct2d-and-winforms-it-just-works/ ). Unfortunately I don't know what specific combination of all the magic window styles and other things I was using at the time. It is possible, however. And it was certainly using hardware acceleration with `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget`.

From my blog post, it seems that the window's HWND was left alone, and it had one child HWND that was used for D2D rendering. That child window then had the buttons and other standard controls as child HWNDs.

Comment: Thanks, interesting that you made it work. I have tried adding the window styles WS_EX_COMPOSITED and WS_CLIPSIBLINGS (I am using c++) to the dialog, the parent window, but the buttons are still being overwritten by the dialog's other child window on which I use Direct2D BeginDraw()/EndDraw(). I create that window with CreateWindowEx(WS_CHILD, dialogHwnd) so it is a sibling of the buttons. I'll have to mess around with it more.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to manually restrict your rendering to a certain region you can use layers (`ID2D1Layer` objects). 
More info here [Layers Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756654(v=vs.85).aspx)

If the visible region is rectangular it may be simpler to use axis aligned clips via methods  `PushAxisAlignedClip` and `PopAxisAlignedClip`. 
[ID2D1RenderTarget::PushAxisAlignedClip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742855(v=vs.85).aspx)

Another method of restricting drawing to a certain shape is to render it to a bitmap and then use this bitmap via a bitmap brush in the `FillGeomtry` method.
[ID2D1RenderTarget::FillGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371933(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I would like Direct2D to not overwrite the buttons and other controls of a dialog (created in a regular dialog editor), so Layers or FillGeometry would require to enter by hand the coordinates of every button/control. I just saw Rick Brewster's answer, I tried it and for now it doesn't work but if it did, it would avoid any manual coordinate work...

Comment: If the automatic clipping doesn't work for you, you could try to set it yourself, e.g. via SelectClipRgn. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183436(v=vs.85).aspx You'll need to calculate and provide the region yourself though.

Comment: As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd372260.aspx#clipping_an_arbitrary_shape, layers perform better than bitmap brushes. Should go above #3 in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Fixed by calling CreateWindowEx LAST for the D2D child HWND.
So AFTER all the other child windows are created.