# Direct2D - preserve the existing content and overwrite the new values

Tags: c++, graphics, mfc, 2d, direct2d

I am planning to develop a XY Plotter for my application. To give some basic idea, how it should look like (of course the implementation would be different), please refer [here](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/Images/xy_4_2_lg.png) and [here](http://www.udel.edu/johnmack/apec324/excel_lab1/xy_plot2.png).

During the simulation (let's assume, it takes 4 hours to complete the simulation), on a fixed X axis, the new Y values should be (over)written.

But, the problem with Direct2D is that, every time `pRenderTarget->BeginDraw()` is called, the existing Drawing(/Plot/BitMap/Image, etc) is deleted and a new image is being drawn. Therefore I would lose the old values.

Of course, I can always buffer the old Y values in a buffer/variable and use it in the next drawing. But, the simulation runs for 4 hours and unfortunately I can't afford to save all the Y values. That's why, I need to render/draw the new Y values on the existing target-image/plot/etc.

And, If don't call `pRenderTarget->EndDraw()` within a definite amount of time, my application would crash due to resource constraints.

How do I prevent this problem and achieve the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is quite a complex requirement - it's more difficult than it appears! Direct2D is an [Immediate-Mode drawing API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ff684178(v=vs.85).aspx). There is no state maintenance or persistence of what you have drawn to the screen in immediate mode graphics.

In most immediate-mode graphics APIs, there is the concept of clipping and dirty rects. In Direct2D you can use one of [these three techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14855912/303612) to draw to a subset of the screen. Rendering offscreen to bitmap and double-buffering might be a good technique to try. e.g. your process becomes:

- Draw to off-screen bitmap
- Blit bitmap to screen
- On new data, draw to a new bitmap / combine with existing bitmaps

This technique will only work if your plot is not scrolling or changing in scale as you append new data / draw.